# gatsby - htmlComponentRenderer.default is not a function

Tags: html, reactjs, gatsby, react-dom

I am new to gatsby's and I am building a 404 error page. From the last couple of hours, I am getting this error

```
TypeError: htmlComponentRenderer.default is not a function

  - render-html.js:30 _bluebird.default
    [callhippowebsite]/[gatsby]/dist/utils/worker/render-html.js:30:36

  - debuggability.js:384 Promise._execute
    [callhippowebsite]/[bluebird]/js/release/debuggability.js:384:9

  - promise.js:518 Promise._resolveFromExecutor
    [callhippowebsite]/[bluebird]/js/release/promise.js:518:18

  - promise.js:103 new Promise
    [callhippowebsite]/[bluebird]/js/release/promise.js:103:10

  - render-html.js:28 _bluebird.default.map.path
    [callhippowebsite]/[gatsby]/dist/utils/worker/render-html.js:28:47

  - util.js:16 tryCatcher
    [callhippowebsite]/[bluebird]/js/release/util.js:16:23

  - map.js:68 MappingPromiseArray._promiseFulfilled
    [callhippowebsite]/[bluebird]/js/release/map.js:68:38

  - promise_array.js:115 MappingPromiseArray.PromiseArray._iterate
    [callhippowebsite]/[bluebird]/js/release/promise_array.js:115:31

  - promise_array.js:79 MappingPromiseArray.init
    [callhippowebsite]/[bluebird]/js/release/promise_array.js:79:10

  - map.js:37 MappingPromiseArray._asyncInit
    [callhippowebsite]/[bluebird]/js/release/map.js:37:10

  - async.js:97 _drainQueueStep
    [callhippowebsite]/[bluebird]/js/release/async.js:97:12

  - async.js:86 _drainQueue
    [callhippowebsite]/[bluebird]/js/release/async.js:86:9

  - async.js:102 Async._drainQueues
    [callhippowebsite]/[bluebird]/js/release/async.js:102:5

  - async.js:15 Immediate.Async.drainQueues [as _onImmediate]
    [callhippowebsite]/[bluebird]/js/release/async.js:15:14


npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! gatsby-starter-react-bootstrap@0.1.0 build: `gatsby build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the gatsby-starter-react-bootstrap@0.1.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\yashraj\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-12-11T12_02_30_237Z-debug.log
```

here is my 404.js file

```
import React from "react"

import Layout from "../components/layout"
import SEO from "../components/seo"

const NotFoundPage = () => (
  <Layout>
    <SEO title="404: Not found" />
    <h1>NOT FOUND</h1>
    <p>You just hit a route that doesn&#39;t exist... the sadness.</p>
 
  </Layout>
)

export default NotFoundPage
```

I don't know what I am doing wrong. any help is appreciated

Comment: Have you tried upgrading your packages, removing cache ( running `gatsby clean`) and rebuilding again?

Comment: @FerranBuireu yes bro I tried still it is giving the same error

Comment: Have you touched/edited any other configuration files?

Comment: I have the same issue - did you find out what happened?

Comment: @LucasArundell no man. i used new gatsby starter and it worked